# How to divide a single table cell in two columns?

Tags: tables, columns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to divide a table row into several columns?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28754/how-to-divide-a-table-row-into-several-columns)

I want to make a table. This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
  \hline 
  \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{TOTAL OF POINTS}} & \hspace{2.5cm} TEACHERS \hspace{2.5cm} & Number \\                                                                       & (Name and sign)  & (President      \\                                                                       &                                & Number of points) \\
  \hline                                                                   
First test\hspace{1cm} Second test &  & \\
                                                     &  &  \\
                                                     &  &  \\
   \cline{2-2}
                                                     &  &  \\
                                                     &  &  \\
                                                     &  &  \\               
                          \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I draw a line between First test and second test like the picture?

Comment: Try nesting a table.

Comment: Please always get rid of all packages in your code that aren't necessary for your example, like I did in my edit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's more natural to think of those as two separate columns, and to keep the table heads in a single multi-line cell, something like:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=15mm,top=20 mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{document}

\vspace{0.5 cm}
\begin{tabular}{| *2{>{\centering}m{3cm}| }
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}|}
  \hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{TOTAL OF POINTS}} &
TEACHERS \par (Name and sign) &
Number (President Number of points) \\
  \hline                                                                   
First test & Second test &  & \\
                                               &      &  &  \\
                                                &     &  &  \\
   \cline{3-3}
                                                &     &  &  \\
                                                &     &  &  \\
                                                &     &  &  \\               
                          \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to align this table fit width page?

Comment: @minthao_2011 see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150987/1090