# How to align this table fit the page-width?

Tags: longtable

I want to align this table. This is mycode

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=20mm,top=20 mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{longtable}{|p{10.8 cm}|p{6 cm}|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\textit{Solve}}}&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\textit{Result}}} \\
\hline 
 &\\
 &\\
 &\\
 &\\
 &\\
 &\\
&\\
 \hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to align this table fit page width when I change my set up in `geometry?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The width of the text block is `\textwidth` the width of the table is the width of your cells plus `2\tabcolsep` padding for each cell plus `\ararryrulewidth` for each vertical line so

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=15mm,right=20mm,top=20 mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{longtable}{
|p{0.7\dimexpr \textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}|
 p{0.3\dimexpr \textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}|
}
\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\textit{Solve}}}&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{\textit{Result}}} \\
\hline 
 &\\
 &\\
 &\\
 &\\
 &\\
 &\\
&\\
 \hline 
\end{longtable}
```

\end{document}

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `tabularx` package to automatically calculate the size of some columns.

The basic command to use is

`\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}`

That command creates a table taking the width of the text with two columns. From the `tabularx`  (`texdoc tanbularx`) manual:

> Normally all X columns in a single table are set to the same width, however it is possible to make tabularx set them to different widths. A preamble argument of `{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X}` specifies two columns, the second will be three times as wide as the first. However if you want to play games like this you should follow the following two rules.
>
> • Make sure that the sum of the widths of all the X columns is unchanged. (In the above example, the new widths still add up to twice the default width, the same as two standard X columns.)
>
> • Do not use \multicolumn entries which cross any X column.
> As with most rules, these may be broken if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Will this also have the functionality to span across multiple pages?