# Table column partially colored and how to vertically center text inside table

Tags: longtable, colortbl

I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{.3\textwidth}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.7\textwidth}|}
\hline
\cellcolor{gray!30}Donnée & \cellcolor{gray!30}Définition \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|p{\textwidth}|}{\cellcolor{green!30} \centering \bfseries Semis} \\
\hline
text & text
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Here's what I get :
[image]

Why the second line is not entirely colored in green? How to fix it?

Second question : how to center **vertically** my text inside the columns?

Comment: you will have had warnings about over full boxes: `|p{.3\textwidth}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.7\textwidth}|}` is too wide by the width of 3 rules and 6 tabcolsep. `\multicolumn{2}{|p{\textwidth}|}` is a different width, it is just wider that textwidth by the width of 2 rules and 4 tabcolsep, this difference accounting for the colour gap.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, how to fix that?

Comment: see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150987/1090

Comment: Comment aside: don't forget loading `inputenc` to obtain accented letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was enough to replace the `p` specifier in `\multicolumn` to have both a simpler code and a solution to your problem.

By the way, since you load `longtable` and `tabularx`, you might consider loading `ltablex` instead: it loads the former and extends the possibilities of longtable to the tabularx environment (essentially without changing its syntax). Also, you don't need to load `color` if you load `xcolor`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ltablex} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{.3\textwidth}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.7\textwidth}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}Donnée & Définition \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{green!30}\bfseries Semis} \\
\hline
text & text\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For vertically centred cell contents, the simplest thing to do is to use `tabularx`, redefining the `X` column type as `m{…}` rather than `p{…}`. The `cellspace` or `makecell` package allow to have less tight vertical spacing in cells, unfortunately, none works with colour commands in tables — cellspace works with `l`, `c` or `c` types, though, as one can see in the middle row of the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\hsize=0.3\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{ >{\hsize=0.7\hsize}X}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X, Y, Z}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Z|}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}Donnée & Définition : Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|Sc|}{\cellcolor{green!30}\bfseries Semis} \\
\hline
text & Text with descenders: gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy gjpqy\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The font axes is vertically centred, I think. Look at the lowercase letters. If you centre capital letters, lowercase won't be: it's an optical effect due  to the very tight vertical spacing in default latex tables. Anyway, I'll modify my code in a moment, I hope you'll it better looking.

Comment: In this example yes. But if I have big paragraph in the second column?

Comment: @user230137: I posted a code with an example of what can be done with multilined paragraphs. Vertical spacing is not wholly satisfactory, due to problems with colour in tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ltablex,ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}% or {>{\RaggedRight}m{#1}} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}  
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| p{0.3\textwidth} | X |}\hline
\rowcolor{gray!30}Donnée & Définition : Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text\\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{green!30}\bfseries Semis} \\\hline
text & \blindtext\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The missing lines in the output are only a problem with the pdf viewer and the magnification.

[image]